# Filtering Gmail by day of the week

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I currently receive emails every weekday from a service I subscribe to. These quickly clog up my inbox however, so I've decided that while the information I receive is important to my work, I only really need an update every two days.

I therefore want to create a filter that sifts out emails received on a Monday, Wednesday or Friday, and deletes the rest.

There is a header in each email mentioning today's date, but unfortunately filtering any message that contains "Tuesday" or "Thursday" results in a lot of false positives, as most of these emails also mention events happening on other days.

---

A couple of inroads I can think of:

1. **Is there anything that can be done with the timestamps on each email?**
2. **The format of the header date is, for example, Friday 08 March 2013. Is there any way to utilize this to distinguish it from the word Friday appearing in the text of the email, say?**

Comment: Just to add, when I say 'header', I don't mean subject. The date is still in the message text; it just appears right at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail has a very powerful [filtering system](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en).

You could create a filter like `If email is from:semi-valuable-email-service.com AND contains:"Monday OR Wednesday OR Friday" THEN send it to trash`

Answer (score 1):

Sputnik, I doubt that is possible. Gmail has a special Javascript language, together with the rest of Google Drive, you might need to get your hands dirty.

A simpler solution: it sounds like you only want to receive emails every two days (Monday, Wednesday, Friday). What about filtering, for instance, the odd days? (1,3,..31)

One week you will receive the email on (Tuesday, Thursday and Saturday), the other week you will receive (Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Sunday). Not perfect, but ...