# How to use complex filtering queries in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

I am playing with different/complex filtering queries/string in Gmail.

I found [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126527/21486) (to my own question):

```
after:1552896000 before:1552924800
```

And I was able to use it without any problems, i.e. I managed to filter e-mails with given dates.

Then I found [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/41969/21486):

```
If email is from:semi-valuable-email-service.com AND contains:"Monday OR Wednesday OR Friday" THEN send it to trash
```

and got a bit lost.

Is this a real string to be pasted somewhere into Gmail (where?) or a pseudo-code to explain filter settings that need to be applied?

Where should I put queries as complex as above? When I try to [create a rule to filter my emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en), all that I see is a filter configuration box with some simple fields and no place to put a query directly.

Actually, I don't need queries as complex as above, but I'd like to merge two or more simple queries (as in the first example, if possible) to [filter out e-mails sent in a given period of time for two or more days](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/126516/21486):

```
after:1502294400 before:1502352000 AND after:1552896000 before:1552924800
```

But I am getting no results, neither from first nor from the second day. Is this possible at all in Gmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a real string to be pasted somewhere into Gmail (where?) or a pseudo-code to explain filter settings that need to be applied?

It's a real thing and you are supposed to use it (just a part of it) in the search bar:

```
from:semi-valuable-email-service.com AND contains:"Monday OR Wednesday OR Friday"
```

[image: 0]

To list emails from two days you need to use **`OR`** instead of **`AND`** and endclose it with **`()`** like:

```
(after:1552698000 before:1552777200) OR (after:1551834000 before:1551913200)
```

This will list all emails from **16th and 6th March 2019** received between **1 AM and 11 PM**

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for a quick, sharp yet to-the-point answer. Just to clarify. Is there any limit for how long the query could be, so Gmail won't die on processing it? I have to go through like hundreds (600+) of days, each time looking for mails received in given period of time. Right now I am doing this manually. Can I "bind" with OR, the way you showed, like dozens or hundreds of such query parameters?

Comment: limit is **1894** characters